# making new dropdown select in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, drop-down-menu, handlebars.js

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm still figuring out what's best for the application I'm doing at the moment.

So I'm now having a dropdown which is using select tag and #each tag like this :

```
{{#x-select action="someAction" value=some.value}}
      <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select category</option>
        {{#each cate in categori }}
          {{#x-option value=cate.id}}
            {{cate.name}}
          {{/x-option}}
        {{/each}}
      {{/x-select}}
```

I want this part can be reusable and repopulate so it can duplicate into infinite choice like after I chose the dropdown, it will show my choice and make another dropdown to show if there is any choice related to the previous drop-down, so I might be having 2, 3 or more drop-down depending how many child it has but only using this one select tag, and all the data is depending from API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can. This is why we say "component".

Have a look at [ember-form-for](https://github.com/martndemus/ember-form-for/blob/master/addon/templates/components/form-controls/select.hbs), [ember-one-way-controls](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-one-way-controls/blob/master/addon/templates/components/one-way-select.hbs) and [ember-bootstrap](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/app/templates/components/bs-select.hbs) addons' select components. You can provide similar API for your select component.

Also instead of reinventing the wheels, you can use these addons. We are using [ember-bootstrap](http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/components/) addon in our project. (We used ember-form-for but we'll stop using it in a near future because we need more customizations.)